# Spring MVC + STS + Maven: WebSecurity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring Security with my web app. I have included the following in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.6.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.22</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.7-1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1-1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
  <version>0.32</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.6</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
  <version>4.7.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, when I extend the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a class named CustomWebSecurityConfigurer, I get this error from STS:

```
The type org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The hierarchy of the type CustomWebSecurityConfigurer is inconsistent

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

I am using Spring Tools Suite 3.8.3.RELEASE

I also tried to add Spring Framework Bom to my dependecy management as described in the [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#maven) but I still get the error.

This error do not appear when I change the version of spring-security-config to the following:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

My CustomWebSecurityConfigurer contains nothing yet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public CustomWebSecurityConfigurer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }

}
```

I get the error during compile time.

Comment: share your full pom.xml

Comment: share `CustomWebSecurityConfigurer` too. Also when are you getting this error; on compile time in STS or when running?

Comment: Use all `spring-security` jars of same version. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this is that it is unable to find the WebSecurity.class file but it should be present in the library as you have added the required dependency. That implies the problem is 
**Either these libraries are not on the build path**
 So make sure these libraries are on the build path.

 **Or the dependencies (jar files) hasn't been downloaded** (this may not be the case).
*If none of the above mentioned problems exist, then clean the project and maven update it. If that too doesn't work then simply refresh your STS, exit and start it again*
 
**Another solution is Forcefully update snapshots (maven)**
Right click on the project, maven -> update project [dont forget to check force update]. check this image .[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tahir. I tried that already but it didn't work. I think its a maven bug, so what I did is I deleted the ~/.m2/repository folder and then I restarted my STS. It worked.